# How to calculate conditional entropy by multiple groups in R ..where did I go wrong

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I've read many questions related to mine, however I can't figure out what's wrong with my code

The package I use is "dplyr" & "infotheo"

Usage of infotheo here is `condentropy(time2, time1)`

my data is like

```
id <- c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3")
cond <- c("1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2")
time1 <- c("1", "3", "3", "2", "3", "3", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1")
time2 <- c("3", "3", "2", "3", "3", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1" ,"1")
df <- data.frame(id, cond, time1, time2)
```

I want to calculate it by id & condition, which means I'll get 6 entropy values from 3 person with two conditions. Here is my code

```
df %>%
group_by(df$id, df$cond) %>%
summarize(condentropy(df$time2, df$time1))
```

why I only got one value for all the groups?

[image]

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: what is `condentropy`?

Comment: It's conditional entropy. It takes two vectors, X and Y, as input and returns the conditional entropy. Usage is   condentropy(X, Y=NULL)  , library(condentropy)

Comment: It's great, that you provide [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question, but key you include _all_ relevant libraries/package, if they are needed for the _minimal, but complete reproducible example_. Please keep asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

First, convert you data to numics

```
df <- df %>% type_convert()

-- Column specification ------------------------------------------
cols(
  id = col_double(),
  cond = col_double(),
  time1 = col_double(),
  time2 = col_double()
)
```

Second, get at finding relevant means,

```
df  %>%
    group_by(id, cond) %>%
    summarise(mean = mean(id))
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'id'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   id [3]
     id  cond  mean
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1
2     1     2     1
3     2     1     2
4     2     2     2
5     3     1     3
6     3     2     3
```

Third, study [this page](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html) for addition examples.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the time columns to numeric, perform the grouping and summarize.  Do not use df$ with dplyr verbs and be sure to assign the value of condentropy(...) to a column name.  The subject of the question refers to mean but the code suggests you want to calculate the conditional entropy so we provide both.

```
library(dplyr)
library(infotheo)

df %>%
  mutate(time1 = as.numeric(time1), time2 = as.numeric(time2)) %>%
  group_by(id, cond) %>%
  summarize(cond_ent = condentropy(time2, time1), 
            mean1 = mean(time1), mean2 = mean(time2), .groups = "drop")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `type.convert(as.is = TRUE)` to get numeric variables and then `summarise` with `across`:
You don't have to use `$`

**This one :**

```
library(dplyr)
library(infotheo)
df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  type.convert(as.is=TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(id, cond) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(c(time1, time2)))
```

Output:

```
     id  cond  mean
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1     1  2.25
2     1     2  2.75
3     2     1  2   
4     2     2  1.5 
5     3     1  1.5 
6     3     2  1.5
```

**OR**

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  type.convert(as.is=TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(id, cond) %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with("time"), mean))
```

Output:

```
     id  cond time1 time2
  <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1   2     2.5
2     1     2   2.5   3  
3     2     1   2     2  
4     2     2   2     1  
5     3     1   1.5   1.5
6     3     2   1.5   1.5
```